# Robotium Test case for Android

Tags: robotium

how to write JUnit test case for robotium

what are all the Robotium methods we use to automate ?

is there any resources or tutor available ?

Answer (score 0):

Download is at this link: http://code.google.com/p/robotium/downloads/detail?name=robotium-solo-3.2.1-javadoc.jar

After you download, just change the file extension to .zip and you will have everything you need regarding the methods and functions used.

Hope this helps.

Blaine